# Cake build fails on OS X, can't find msbuild.exe

Tags: macos, xamarin, cakebuild

I'm trying to setup Cake build for my Xamarin project. It is working perfectly on Windows but fails on OS X (El Captain).
[build.sh is here](https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider/blob/master/build.sh), [build.cake is here](https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider/blob/master/build.cake).

Build fails with on NuGetRestore this message:

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5'.
MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5/msbuild.exe'.
An error occured when executing task 'Restore-NuGet-Packages'.
Error: NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

./build.sh -v "Diagnostic" gives:

```
Executing: /Users/artur/sources/xamarin-range-slider/tools/NuGet.exe restore "/Users/artur/sources/xamarin-range-slider/Xamarin.RangeSlider.sln" -Verbosity detailed -NonInteractive
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> NuGet.CommandLineException: MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5/msbuild.exe'.
  at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.GetProjectReferences (System.String msbuildDirectory, System.String[] projectPaths, Int32 timeOut) <0x34e8ed0 + 0x00677> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.DetermineRestoreInputs () <0x3452690 + 0x002af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand+<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__23.MoveNext () <0x3451688 + 0x0028b> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) <0x1d1d960 + 0x00049> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1d1f150 + 0x000c8> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () <0x1d1ef70 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute () <0x343a298 + 0x00213> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore (System.String workingDirectory, System.String[] args) <0x718cc0 + 0x005e0> in <filename unknown>:0
---> (Inner Exception #0) NuGet.CommandLineException: MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5/msbuild.exe'.
  at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.GetProjectReferences (System.String msbuildDirectory, System.String[] projectPaths, Int32 timeOut) <0x34e8ed0 + 0x00677> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.DetermineRestoreInputs () <0x3452690 + 0x002af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand+<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__23.MoveNext () <0x3451688 + 0x0028b> in <filename unknown>:0 <---

An error occured when executing task 'Restore-NuGet-Packages'.
Error: Cake.Core.CakeException: NuGet: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
  at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1[TSettings].ProcessExitCode (Int32 exitCode) <0x3a8b208 + 0x000fb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1[TSettings].Run (Cake.Core.Tooling.TSettings settings, Cake.Core.IO.ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments, Cake.Core.IO.ProcessSettings processSettings, System.Action`1 postAction) <0x3a34a88 + 0x00177> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1[TSettings].Run (Cake.Core.Tooling.TSettings settings, Cake.Core.IO.ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments) <0x3a34a48 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore.NuGetRestorer.Restore (Cake.Core.IO.FilePath targetFilePath, Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore.NuGetRestoreSettings settings) <0x3a34328 + 0x0004b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.NuGetAliases.NuGetRestore (ICakeContext context, Cake.Core.IO.FilePath targetFilePath, Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore.NuGetRestoreSettings settings) <0x3a33f18 + 0x0012f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at CakeBuildScriptImpl.NuGetRestore (Cake.Core.IO.FilePath targetFilePath, Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore.NuGetRestoreSettings settings) <0x3a33ed8 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at CakeBuildScriptImpl+<Execute>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () <0x3a33e40 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Core.CakeTaskBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4.<Does>b__3 (ICakeContext context) <0x3a33e20 + 0x00014> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Core.ActionTask.Execute (ICakeContext context) <0x3a33d68 + 0x00059> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Core.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute (Cake.Core.CakeTask task, ICakeContext context) <0x3a33b18 + 0x00162> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTask (ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch, Cake.Core.CakeTask task, Cake.Core.CakeReport report) <0x3a33538 + 0x00099> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: there is an open issue regarding this on github. Not very helpful right now but stay tuned: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3085

Comment: @jzeferino thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because an version on NuGet.exe in path that that unaware of mono.

By running `build.sh -v "Diagnostic"` you'll get an detailed log of how the NuGet command line is called for the restore operation.

There's also an overload for [NuGetRestore(FilePath, ​NuGetRestoreSettings)​](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget.restore/71880157) on the [NuGetRestoreSettings](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget.restore/71880157) you can set the [Verbosity](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget.restore/71880157/f91e9de0) property to [Detailed](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget/4efc43a2) to get more verbose logging from the NuGet command line.

If it's not the nuget.exe in your project tools folder you could change the bootstrapper to add tools folder first in path. (you can also set the ToolsPath property on the [NuGetRestoreSettings](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.nuget.restore/71880157) if you just want to test that theory.

If it's running the path to NuGet.exe, check which version of nuget you have by running nuget without arguments (`mono ./tools/nuget.exe`).

For reference this seems to be an known issue with NuGet console, reference GitHub issue [NuGet/Home#3085](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3085)

Comment: NuGet Version: 3.4.4.1321

Comment: Updated post, added diagnostic output.

Comment: add this to your nuget restore:     `NuGetRestore(solutionFile, new NuGetRestoreSettings { Verbosity =  NuGetVerbosity.Detailed});`. Ive tested  your source and I'm getting the same problem. I have here a working code with nuget restores from my code. I guess this is not nuget version related.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you delete nuget.exe and change `https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe` to `https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v3.5.0-rc1/NuGet.exe` or `https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v2.8.6/nuget.exe` in build.sh?

Comment: This seems to be an known issue with mono and nuget.exe, so trying an earlier version could sort the issue
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3085

Comment: I've already pasted that information in the question comment section.

Comment: Marking this reply as answer. https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v2.8.6/nuget.exe helped.

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov what was the solution you end up with?

Comment: Use an older version of the nuget.exe

Comment: @jzeferinoyes, I'm using dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v2.8.6/nuget.exe